# jQuery unmute HTML5 video when in viewport

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple muted html5 videos looping on my page and would like to unmute the one that's in the viewport.

I'm using this [plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/viewport) to check if elements are in the viewport and I'm guessing my solution is something like this

HTML:

```
<video autoplay loop muted>
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video autoplay loop muted>
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video autoplay loop muted>
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

jQuery:

```
$('video:in-viewport').prop('muted', false);
```

but it's not working for me, it unmutes all the videos without discriminating on their visibility. Please help.

Comment: Hmm I would assume that means it is detecting more than one video in the viewport. Try placing them each in their own div that takes up the entire viewable screen just to make sure

Comment: @Pseudonym they're about 2 body-heights apart each.

Comment: Just tried this is a fiddle, and got all videos selected when they were all in the viewport, still working on out of viewport stuff stand by

Comment: @Natsu let me try that

Comment: you should tell us how you are using this call, it should be used mixed with a scroll event I guess

Comment: Post your entire code so I can take a look please as I was able to get it working

Comment: Works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hw0n3t6p/

Comment: I found what the problem was. I was using the call in an external .js file and everything worked as expected when I added the code to the html. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is something wrong with another part of your code, perhaps you didn't set the viewport correctly?

I tried this with the autoplay property and your posted code worked fine:

HTML:

```
<video autoplay loop muted height="900">
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video autoplay loop muted>
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>

<video autoplay loop muted>
     <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

JS:

```
$('video:in-viewport').prop('autoplay', false);
```

Fiddle where you can see it working

http://jsfiddle.net/uruddhun/